# Hook into WCF service before deserialization of client request and after serialization of response

Tags: .net, wcf, hook, net.tcp

Is there a way to get a hook into every call from a client made to a WCF service

1. as soon as a client request is noticed at the server side (i.e. before deserialization of the request)
2. after serialization of the response has finished

so that e.g. those points can be added to latency measurements. It's OK if this is specific to `net.tcp`, which is what we are using.

I guess adding a `IDispatchMessageInspector` would allow me to hook in *before deserialization of the request* (albeit after creation of a `Message object`, and I'd like to hook in even BEFORE that), but not *after serialization of the response*.

Comment: Is this something you want for dev only environments? Or is it a production requirement?

Comment: @TomRedfern It should work in PROD as well

Answer (score 2):

To hook in **before deserializion of requests**, I am wrapping the `MessageEncoder` (for which I also had to wrap the `MessageEncoderFactory`, and the `MessageEncodingBindingElement`)

and then I can hook into the `MessageEncoder.ReadMessage()` overloads.

---

To hook in **after serialization of the response**, I am wrapping the `IOutputChannel` (for which I also had to wrap the `IChannelListener` and the `TcpTransportBindingElement`),

and then I can hook into the `IOutputChannel.Send()`/`IOutputChannelEndSend()` overloads.

That's as close to the wire as I got, and close enough for me.

Comment: Is there a centralised place to hook into after deserialisation of requests?

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you require is to capture messages that are being sent/received when a given service is called, you can use the suggestions from the following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735120(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726(v=vs.110).aspx

This will allow you to capture to disk all the messages being sent and received, in Xml.